# Can I change the plumbing pipe direction?

Tags: plumbing, framing, plumbing-fixture

I am finishing my basement and currently in the process of framing for the pipes and ducts.

[image]

the black pipe extends too far out of the ceiling cavity and is positioned diagonally. I aim to replicate a configuration similar to the one shown in the second image.

[image]

However, I've encountered an issue. As seen in the image provided,

Since I lack experience in plumbing, I seek advice on whether using a 90-degree elbow is the appropriate approach for this situation. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The limiting factors are as follows:

1. The fall on the trap arm cannot exceed the diameter of the pipe. For a 2" pipe with a grade of 1/4" per foot, the maximum length from the vent connection to the trap would be 8 feet (2 ÷ 0.25 = 8). For 1-1/2 pipe, it would be 6 feet.
   [image]
2. The maximum change in direction is 135°.
   [image]

So as long as you meet these conditions (note these are as per my local plumbing code, confirm with your local plumbing code) you should be fine.